# Unable to fetch an item from a webpage in the right way

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

When I run my script to fetch the phone number from a webpage, the script does it in a messy way. I'm pasting two different scripts that I've written to achieve the same goal.

I want to stick to the oneliner solution (the second script). How can I modify my second script to get rid of whitespaces like what the first script does? They bot works in the same way but why the variations in the output?

[Check out this website link](http://www.fretonline.com/Transport.php?transporteur=EUROM2OCAS&&Nom_Transporteur=EUROMESSAGE_EXPRESS&&Transport_Ville=CASABLANCA)

This works almost accurate (just one whitespace comes along):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "replace with above link"

req = requests.get(url)
sauce = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
for items in sauce.select_one("table[width='610']").select("tr"):
    for item in items.select("td"):
        if "phone" in item.text:
            print(item.find_next_sibling().get_text())
```

I wish to make my script like below. It also fetches the right item but lots of whitespaces coming along.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "replace with above link"

req = requests.get(url)
sauce = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
for items in sauce.select_one("table[width='610']").select("tr"):
    phone = [item.find_next_sibling().get_text() for item in items.select("td") if "phone" in item.text]
    print(phone)
```

The result I wish to have like (no whitespaces around):

```
212 22 24 24 57
```

This is how it is embedded in that site:

```
<tr>
            <td height="20"><font color="#787878" size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>Téléphone
              :</strong></font></td>
            <td><strong><font color="#919CBA" size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
              212 22 24 24 57              </font></strong></td>
          </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) to remove trailing and leading spaces in the string.

For the first solution just do this:

```
phone = []

for items in sauce.select_one("table[width='610']").select("tr"):
    for item in items.select("td"):
        if "phone" in item.text:
            numbers.append(item.find_next_sibling().text.strip())

print(phone)
```

The second solution does not work as you are creating and printing a new list for each iteration of the loop. If you want to use list comprehension you would have to do the same nested loop:

```
 phone = [item.find_next_sibling().get_text().strip() for items in sauce.select_one("table[width='610']").select("tr") for item in items.select("td") if "phone" in item.text]

 print(phone)
```

Personally I think the first alternative is easier to follow.

Comment: I knew this is the first possible solution I may get cause i tried it in the first place. [Hit this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1nmcb9885w7eh9w/image.jpg?dl=0) to see the output it produces.

Comment: Sorry, never tested the code. It is because you are creating and printing a list for each iteration of the loop. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: What does it differ from my first script? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your first solution works fine except for not using strip(). The second code example you posted clearly does not work in the same way as you are creating and printing a list for every iteration of the loop. I have updated the answer with a solution using list comprehension as well.

Comment: No way. You have made it. Thankssss a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot check or test your example (I got a request error urllib3)
I think you need to try something like this:

```
req = requests.get(url)
sauce=BeautifulSoup(req.content,"html5lib")

table=sauce.find("div",{"color":"#919CBA"})

for rows in table:
    tabs=rows.find_all("tr")
    for trtag in tabs:
        phone.append(trtag.find("td"))

print(phone)
```